# How to get a PDF from other two PDFs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

At a bus stop, suppose the interval between two buses (bus headway) is $x$, PDF of $x$ is $f(x)$. The in-stop waiting time for a passenger is $y$. For a bus interval $x$, suppose the arrival of passengers satisfies uniform distribution with PDF:

$$
g(y|x) =
\begin{cases}
1/x, & \text{if $0 \le y\le x$}\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$

To derive the PDF of $y$ without the intermedia $x$, there is
$$p(y) = \int_0^{+\infty}g(y|x){f(x)}dx 
= \int_0^{x}{\frac{1}{x}f(x)}dx $$

Here is the problem. $p(y)$ should be a function of $y$, but why the rightmost of the equation above is only a function of $x$, not $y$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Extended_form_2

Comment: Can you help me with the updated question? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should be a function of $y$, so clearly you have the bounds muddled up.   $x$ should not appear there.

Look to the support for $g(y\mid x)$, it is $0\leq y\leq x$, so when "integrating out" the $x$, that leaves: $0\leq y$ as the support, and the integral is over $x$ from $y$ to infinity.

$$p(y)~{=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac 1x\mathbf 1_{0\leq y\leq x}\right) f(x)\mathsf d x\\= \mathbf 1_{0\leq y} \int_y^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x}\,\mathsf d x}$$

Of course, also the support for $f(x)$ itself needs to be considered.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't really understand how to manipulate form the first line of your equation to the second line.

Comment: You are integrating $x$ over the support $0\leq y\leq x\lt \infty$ for a particular value of $y$, which is non-negative. The integral's variable, $x$, clearly 'lives' between that $y$ and infinity. $$\int_{\Bbb R} h(x,y)~\mathbf 1_{0\leq y\leq x\lt \infty}~\mathrm d x ~{ =~ \int_\Bbb R\mathbf 1_{y\leq x\lt\infty}~\mathbf 1_{0\leq y\lt \infty}~h(x,y)~\mathsf d x \\ =~\mathbf 1_{0\leq y\lt \infty}~\int_{y\leq x\lt\infty}~h(x,y)~\mathsf d x}$$